# How can I translate this SQL statement to a Linq-to-SQL approach?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-sql

For example, imagine that I want to see if a user exists in my database:

```
Select * from Users where inputID = Users.ID
```

Then if that result brought > 0 items, then the user exists, correct?

How can I do something like this using a pure Linq-to-SQL class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dbContext.Users.Any(x => x.ID == inputID)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var user = dbContext.GetTable<User>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == inputID);
bool userExists = user != null;
```

That will fetch the matching user from the database, if you just want to check for existance you can do this:

```
int matchingUsers = dbContext.GetTable<User>().Count(u => u.ID == inputID);
bool userExists = matchingUsers > 0;
```

or

```
bool userExists = dbContext.GetTable<User>().Any(u => u.ID == inputID);
```

Comment: I have never seen the `GetTable<>` method before. What is the difference between `dbContext.GetTable<User>()` and `dbContext.Users`? Thanks.

Comment: @Deniz Dogan - GetTable is defined on the DataContext class, if you use the linq2sql designer to create entity classes then it creates a subclass of DataContext and defines a property for each db-mapped type. So in this case it will look like `IQueryable<User> Users { get { return this.GetTable<User>(); }}`

Comment: Ah, I see. So the two ways are basically identical. Cool. :)